# Ignore a resources subfolder ends up ignoring all resources folder

Tags: git, maven, gitignore

I started a new maven project and have a resources folder with a "dirty" folder inside, like the following:

```
resources/
     dirty/
          SC/
     SC/
```

It's a folder with csv tables that I'll aplly a script to clean up them.

I want to ignore the "dirty" folder, but not other folders in resources, so I made a .gitignore like the following:

```
.idea
dirty/
```

But, for some reason, it ignores the resources folder completely. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Comment: I don't think it does (ignore the `resources` content). Why do you think it does? Specifically, do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set full path for the `dirty` directory:

```
/resources/dirty/
```

The starting `/` means the root directory where the `.gitignore` is located.

Also, I had similar problem and I ended up using the following approach:

```
// ignore the contents of Assets directory
Assets/*
// but keep track of the following subdirectories inside Assets:
!Assets/dir_to_keep/
!Assets/other_dir_to_keep/
```

Comment: I tried this before, and had the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Refer the `.gitignore` documentation and the example as below on [this link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar
> (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude
> everything within foo/bar):
>
> ```
> $ cat .gitignore
> # exclude everything except directory foo/bar
> /*
> !/foo
> /foo/*
> !/foo/bar
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> But, for some reason, it ignores the resources folder completely.

First, check is the `resource` folder is actually ignored, choosing a file which should not be ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v resource/SC/aFile
```

If it returns nothing, then `resource` is not ignored.

As the OP comments:

> I found that it showed as ignored because there's nothing inside the `resources/SC` folder.
>
> When I run my cleaner script and the clean tables appeared in `resources/SC` the foder color changes from ignored (yellow) to unstaged (red).

Comment: @hilsonjunior What do you see which made you conclude "But, for some reason, it ignores the resources folder completely"?

Comment: the IDE uses yellow for ignored folders, and the resources folder, and the folder were yellow

Comment: @hilsonjunior Is there a `.git` subfolder inside resource? In other words, is resource a nested Git repository?

Comment: I know it's silly, but that make me worried

Comment: @hilsonjunior OK. I did not realized you already accepted a solution. I guess your issue is resolved, then.

Comment: I found that it showed as ignored because there's nothing inside the resources/SC folder.

When I run my cleaner script and the clean tables appeared in resources/SC the foder color changes from ignored (yellow) to unstaged (red)

Comment: @hilsonjunior Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @hilsonjunior what is missing in this answer? You had selected the right answer before.